# How to run rails applications on digitalocean using "rails s" (make it a development environment)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, digital-ocean, unicorn

My issue is that I created a droplet to develop Rails apps in digitalocean .
I used the one-click rails droplet. And now I want to create more rails apps than the default rails app in this droplet.

The issue here is that it comes installed with nginx/unicorn .. And they're always on with path of default rails project in their config files.

Now let's assume I created another rails app(file) and I want to run it using "rails s" instead of default rails app that is created by the droplet. How can I do it?

Note: I don't want to change the file path in configs each time I decide to try another app

PS: I tried stopping the service of unicorn/nginx one at a time and both of them in the same time to use "rail s" to run the app .. But it didn't work .. Web pages were not loading

I know it might be a question of a rookie. But I'm kinda new to these stuff and I'd appreciate it if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you run it with rails s on the server, chances are it will be running with Puma, or if you're on an older version of Rails, Webrick. Unicorn is not involved in that case because Rails is using its own default web server. If you see that 'rails s' is not running in the right environment, it may be  because RAILS_ENV is being set in your shell profile. You can override that by doing:

```
RAILS_ENV=development rails s
```

To launch your console.

That being said, rails s runs on localhost:3000 by default - and in the case you described it would be running on DigitalOcean's localhost - not yours. In order to get to it from your local machine, you would need to set up some sort of reverse proxy to allow connections to DO to get served from localhost. This is what nginx is doing for you - it's facilitating a reverse proxy.

If you want do use your DO server as a development machine for a second rails app you have, you're going to have to create that new rails app on the server, then create the reverse proxy settings in nginx to direct to it, then finally create the unicorn settings to serve it. This is an uncommon way of developing though. I recommend using your local machine to develop, and setting up Capistrano or some other deploy tool to deploy it to DO instead. You'd still need to add the settings in nginx/unicorn for the second app, but it will save you headache down the road.

Comment: A very helpful answer ty.
Just one more thing, I was using codeanywhere and c9 where I could use "rails s -b 0.0.0.0" so that I can view my app from anywhere using their public link. Is it possible to do the same with DO.
And actually I have no isuue in using Puma. I only want to run it as I described because I'm developing using different devices (laptop/iPad) daily. So I can't develop locally. If you could help me with this I'll be so thankful